# Cast Scala String to StringContext and virtually forward references

Tags: scala

In Scala 2.10.0-RC1 there's a wonderful feature, the *[String Interpolation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/string-interpolation.html)*.

This works like this:

```
scala> val x = 1
x: Int = 1

scala> val y = s"Interpolated String $x"
y: String = Interpolated String 1
```

But I'm building a internal DSL with Scala, and therefore I need to handle with a sort of *forward references*. That you have in mind, what the DSL looks like (it's for documentation generation):

```
object Main {

  § > "Heading"

  § >> "Subheading"

  ++ txt """
    Lorem ipsum Abb. ${Main.fig.number} dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
    nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
    sed diam voluptua.
  """

  val fig =
  ++ figure(
    src="https://...",
    desc="example figure"
  )
}
```

But the problem looks semantically like this:

```
object X {
  val y = s"$x with reverse reference"
  val x = 3
}
```

And this doesn't work, because of the virtually forward reference. I can write `x` as `lazy val`, but the compiler moves `x` and makes it for `y` available. But for my DSL design the order of `y` and `x` *must* be preserved!

So far my solution is a closure, like this:

```
object X {
  val y = () => s"$x with reverse reference"
  val x = 3
}
```

This allows me to invoke `X.y()` at the end, when *all* variables are available. But the disadvantage is, the *"ugliness"*, no domain-user will understand this kind of magic!
The domain user must write something like this (but it works!):

```
++ txt (() => s"""
  Lorem ipsum Abb. ${Main.fig.number} dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
  nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
  sed diam voluptua.
""")
```

So the idea is to move the closure magic into my DSL api, but therefore I need to pass `"$x with reverse reference"` as ordinary `String` and resolve this String at the end as `StringContext` (s"..."), which resolves the `$`-references. But so far I found nothing, how to cast this. In short how can I cast `"foo $x bar` to `s"foo $x bar"`?

What I [found](http://dcsobral.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/string-interpolation-on-scala-210.html) is, how to individualize `StringContext`, but don't know how I can use this for my problem:

```
scala> case class StringContext(parts: String*) {
     |   def rr (args: Any*) = scala.StringContext(parts: _*).s(args: _*)
     | }
defined class StringContext

scala> rr"hi"
res3: String = hi

scala> rr"hi $s"
res4: String = hi 1
```

The other idea is a less "noisy" lambda notation, but how can I write something like (or similar) this:

```
++ txt => s"""... ${Main.fig.number} ..."""
```

Such a notation would be reasonable. I don't necessarily to write my own String parser with reference resolving. Anybody an sneaky idea?

The DSL api is semantically built like this:

```
object ++ {
  def txt (s: String) = ...
}
```

Comment: what if you define `y` as lazy? `lazy val y = s"$x with reverse reference"`

Comment: "I can write x as lazy val, but the compiler moves x and makes it for y available. But for my DSL design the order of y and x must be preserved!"

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that you meant ordering in the bytecode

Comment: "I can write x as lazy val" Write `y` as lazy val as @pagoda_5b said.

Comment: This will also confuse the right order. There is a document builded which relies heavily on the order. The classes which are called by `§` or `++` register them self into a list, and this must happen in the right order. Don't focus so much on this lazy-thing, especially because I want to avoid to much magic at the "frontend" for the domain users. :)

Comment: This sounds undesirably fragile--correctness depends on reordering of statements _by the compiler_ that get dependencies right?  Why would one want something like that?  We already have LaTeX (XeTeX, LuaTeX, etc.) to cover that kind of document creation.

Comment: Come on, that's not essential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the idea and solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307418/scala-variable-argument-list-with-call-by-name-possible/), a possible solution looks like this (run-able on *Scala 2.10.0-RC2*):

```
implicit def byname_to_noarg[A](a: => A) = () => a

case class StringContext(parts: String*) {
  def $ (args: (() => Any)*) = () => {
    val unpacked = args.map(a => a())
    scala.StringContext(parts: _*).s(unpacked: _*)
  }
}

class A {
  def meth = "A's result"
}

object X {
  val y = $"foo $x bar ${z.meth}. Forward reference solved."
  val x = 3
  val z = new A
}

// Execute
X.y()
```

Thanks for that, Rex Kerr! :)