# How to execute multiple tasks parallellly?

Tags: scala, concurrency, parallel-processing

I attend the class [Parallel Programming](https://www.coursera.org/learn/parprog1/),  and it shows the parallel interface:

```
def parallel[A, B](taskA: => A, taskB: => B): (A, B) = {
  val ta = taskA
  val tb = task {taskB}
  (ta, tb.join())
}
```

and the following is wrong:

```
def parallel[A, B](taskA: => A, taskB: => B): (A, B) = {
  val ta = taskB
  val tb = task {taskB}.join()
  (ta, tb)
}
```

see the interface more at https://gist.github.com/ChenZhongPu/fe389d30626626294306264a148bd2aa

It also show us the right way to execute four tasks:

```
def parallel[A, B, C, D](taskA: => A, taskB: => B, taskC: => C, taskD: => D): (A, B, C, D) = {
    val ta = task { taskA }
    val tb = task { taskB }
    val tc = task { taskC }
    val td = taskD
    (ta.join(), tb.join(), tc.join(), td)
}
```

My question: if I don't know the number of tasks advance (a List of tasks), how can I call `join` for each tasks correctly?

```
tasks.map(_.join()) // wrong
```

---

**Edit**

The similar discussion also occurs at [Discuss this week's module: Parallel Programming](https://www.coursera.org/learn/parprog1/discussions/weeks/1/threads/Uh8w9yWrEea6-g6AAdRd5w?sort=createdAtDesc)

Comment: Note: `map` returns a new collection with each element transformed by the function.  Maybe you need the transformation without creating the new collection?

Comment: @jwvh how to do it?

Comment: How about just using `foreach` since you are not going to return anything?

Comment: @sebszyller using `foreach` will also execute those tasks sequentially, not parallelly.

Comment: @chenzhongpu I meant joining them not actual execution.

Comment: When you call val t = task { ... }, val keyword initiates task execution. Join is only to collect the result - so your code is correct

Answer (score 3):

## Using [framework](https://gist.github.com/ChenZhongPu/fe389d30626626294306264a148bd2aa) from [Parallel Programming](https://www.coursera.org/learn/parprog1) course

You can implement the method like this:

```
def parallel[A](tasks: (() => A)*): Seq[A] = {
  if (tasks.isEmpty) Nil
  else {
    val pendingTasks = tasks.tail.map(t => task { t() })
    tasks.head() +: pendingTasks.map(_.join())
  }
}
```

(Note that you [can't have variable number of by-name arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307418/scala-variable-argument-list-with-call-by-name-possible) - though this [can change](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5787))

And then use it like that:

```
object ParallelUsage {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()

    // Use a list of tasks:
    val tasks = List(longTask _, longTask _, longTask _, longTask _)
    val results = parallel(tasks: _*)
    println(results)

    // or pass any number of individual tasks directly:
    println(parallel(longTask, longTask, longTask))
    println(parallel(longTask, longTask))
    println(parallel(longTask))
    println(parallel())

    println(s"Done in ${ System.currentTimeMillis() - start } ms")
  }

  def longTask() = {
    println("starting longTask execution")
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    42 + Math.random
  }
}
```

## Using [Scala's parallel collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html)

You can't go simpler than this:

```
val tasks = Vector(longTask _, longTask _, longTask _)
val results = tasks.par.map(_()).seq
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking around for a practical way to build `parallel()` I found it can be built from `Future`.  The paradigm will seem familiar to anyone using modern Javascript `Promises`:

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await,Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def parallel[A, B](taskA: =>A, taskB: =>B): (A,B) = {
  val fB:Future[B] = Future { taskB }
  val a:A = taskA
  val b:B = Await.result(fB, Duration.Inf)
  (a,b)
}
```

This spins off taskB to it own thread and does taskA in the main thread.  We do `taskA` and wait, forever if necessary, for `fB` to finish.  Beware I haven't tested exceptions with this setup and it might stall or misbehave.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by `Future.sequence` and cheating a bit. You need a `Task` implementation that's also a Monad to make this design work.

```
  /** Transforms a `TraversableOnce[Task[A]]` into a `Task[TraversableOnce[A]]`.
   *  Useful for reducing many `Task`s into a single `Task`.
   */
  def parallel[
    A,
    M[X] <: TraversableOnce[X]
  ](in: M[Task[A]])(
    implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[M[Task[A]], A, M[A]],
    executor: ExecutionContext
  ): Task[M[A]] = {
    in.foldLeft(Task.point(cbf(in))) {
      (fr, fa) => for (r <- fr; a <- fa) yield (r += a)
    }.map(_.result())(executor)
  }
```

This can execute operations in parallel for most Scala collections, the only condition is that the `Task` defines `map` and `flatMap`, whichever the implementation is, because you can abstract over the particular collection type using the `implicit builder` construct, that's internal to the Scala library.