# Combine varargs and argument by name

Tags: scala

I'd like to be able to define a function like this:

```
def paralellize(func: ⇒ Unit *) = {
    func.par.foreach(_.apply())
}
```

but it seems that Scala doesn't like it:

```
')' expected but identifier found.
def parallelize(func: => Unit *) = {
                             ^
<console>:3: '=' expected but eof found.
```

I think this is due to the combination of varargs and by name arguments.

My intention is to be able to parallelize arbitrary code easily:

```
parallelize(
     { 
        println("a")
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        println("A")
     },
     { 
        println("b")
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        println("B")
     }
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala variable argument list with call-by-name possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307418/scala-variable-argument-list-with-call-by-name-possible)

Comment: The equivalent would be `Future.sequence(Seq(<futures>))` which gives you more control imo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if i fully understood your question, but if you want pass many functions as argument you can try it like this

```
def paralellize(func: (() => Unit)* ) = {
  func.par.foreach(_.apply())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter variation of Kamil answer:

```
def paralellize(func: () => Unit* ) = 
  func.par.foreach(_.apply())
```

Comment: I got this to compile: `def paralellize(func: (() => Unit)*) = func.par.foreach(_())`